# Why doesn't the WC code auto-fill when importing time via Quickbooks' Desktop SDK (QBXML)?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

We're using the QBXML framework for importing time from our Desktop app, into Quickbooks Desktop.

**The method we're using:**

```
TimeTrackingAdd
```

**Reference:**
[TimeTrackingAdd Quickbooks Desktop API Reference](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/timetrackingadd)

A customer whom is using Workers Compensation codes is finding that it isn't automatically selecting the WC Code based on the payroll item. It's leaving the field blank.

As far as I can tell, the WC code is related to the employee and the payroll item. If the customer is manually inputting into their staff timesheets within Quickbooks, then the WC code is automatically selected as expected.

Unfortunately I don't have access to a Quickbooks version that allows me to use WC codes, and so cannot test it. However it doesn't appear that the QBXML SDK allows for a WC code to be appended to the Time Tracking Add type anyway.

**Does anyone know if auto-selecting the WC code is possible when using the Quickbooks Desktop SDK?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this. The latest 2022 release of Quickbooks has fixed the issue.